# I want to know how to add items from sql database to a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, sqlcommand

This is my code here, I wanted to put this into a listview from sql database, it reads just one and puts just one item in listview, but I want to place all items from database into a listview. my Database have 8 attributes but this code shows only second attribute

```
alinanYemek.GridLines = true;

try
{ 
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        @"select * from YEMEK where PersonelKartID=@pID and OgrenciKartID = @oID", connection);
    if (radio_ID == 'P')
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", _kimlik);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oID", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pID", 0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oID", _kimlik);
    }
    var a = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    lvi.SubItems.Add(a);
    alinanYemek.Items.Add(lvi);
    connection.Close();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    if(_dil == 'T')
        MessageBox.Show("Girdiginiz kisi icin yemek bulmamaktadir");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("There is no meal selected for this person");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why adding by yourself, there's a much easier way to achieve this by DataGridView.

setting [DataGridView.DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can bind to the database automatically.

exmaple : [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Thank you man but I do not want to do this with datagridview because I have to use listView in my school project. By the way I know that I can use that I used it in other form